# Is it possible to get contacts from my Skype account in android?

Tags: android, skype

I have implemented Skype video/audio calling functionality using Intent in my application it is working fine. But now I want to get all contacts list from Skype account is it possible?.

Is there any alternate way to show list of contacts of Skype account please give any idea?

Comment: Have to tried to implement skype Api?

Comment: No. I am doing this by intent

Comment: I think you should use its API to access the accounts here- http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference

Comment: @Shashank can you tell me specific way or uri for do this...please

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this link will be helpful for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886508/how-to-get-skype-info-from-the-android-contact-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886508/how-to-get-skype-info-from-the-android-contact-list)

Answer (score 3):

All contacts (provided they are synced) can be queried with the [`ContactsContract`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) provider. The `RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE` column of the [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table indicates the account type for each entry ("raw" means that it contains all entries, e.g. multiple rows for a single person with multiple aggregated contacts).

To read the Skype contacts, you can do something like this:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
                RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
                new String[] { "com.skype.contacts.sync" },
                null);

int contactNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
ArrayList<String> mySkypeContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

while (c.moveToNext())
{
    /// You can also read RawContacts.CONTACT_ID to query the 
    // ContactsContract.Contacts table or any of the other related ones.
    mySkypeContacts.add(c.getString(contactNameColumn));
}
```

Be sure to also request the `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.