# Get Skype users id and statuses in Android

Tags: android, skype

Is it possible to get users id's and statuses in android?
I am able to get skype contact list, can chat, audio/video calls with skype friends by following these two links.

1)[Is it possible to get contacts from my Skype account in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632350/is-it-possible-to-get-contacts-from-my-skype-account-in-android)

2) http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/01/how-to-make-skype-audiovideo-call-and.html

But now in android app, I want to get skype contact list with their statuses and specific skype user id's.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don t think is possible to have you skype statuses in your app . For example you won t be able to see the statuses if the user does not have the skype app opened .To implement this skype should release a sdk to integrate ..maybe they will do that.

Comment: Raluca, thank you very much for such nice answer. I also searched a lot but could not get any solution.